# cakephp 3 custom sql query with pagination and sorting

Tags: pagination, cakephp-3.0, columnsorting

Im facing a problem with bulk data. I need to join nearly 8 tables to fetch the result so its taking more time for displaying the result. so i thought to build a custom SQL query for that I need to know how to do pagination in cakephp 3 using custom SQL query along with sorting options for the columns in the view.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT t1.f1, t2.f2, t3.f1 
         FROM table1 as t1 
         left join table2 as t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f2 
         left join table3 as t3 on t1.f3 = t3.f1'
 $results = $this->query($sql);
```

i need to paginate and sort the fields based on this query

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Query directly to the Controller's `paginate` function, ex:

```
// Build thea query as complex as required, ex:
$query = $this->Model->find();

$query = $query
    ->select(['total_comments' => $query->func()->count('Comments.id')])
    ->leftJoinWith('Comments.Users', function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['username' => 'markstory']);
    })
    ->group(['Users.id']);

$this->set('data', $this->paginate($query));
```

See:

- [Using the Paginator Directly](http://$this-%3Epaginate($query);)
- [Joining Additional Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#joining-additional-associations)